# Approximate a root of an odd degree polynomial

Tags: code-golf, sequence, open-ended-function, polynomials

Every odd degree polynomial has at least one real root. However this root does not have to be a rational number so your task is to output a sequence of rational numbers that approximates it.

### Rules

- Your input is an odd degree polynomial \$f\$ with integer coefficients in any reasonable format.
- You must output a sequence of rational numbers \$(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\$ such that \$f(\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n) =0\$ using the standard [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules.
- Your solution may fail because of finite precision however it must work in theory, assuming your language has arbitrary precision rational numbers. If your language doesn't support algebraic numbers, you may not
  assume that it does. In particular you may not assume that a `find_roots` built-in returns an infinite precision algebraic number if it doesn't.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
input -> example output

x^3-2 -> 1, 1.2, 1.25, 1.259, ...
x+7 -> -7, -7, -7, ...
x^5-x+1 -> -1.1, -1.167, -1.167304, ...
2x^7-3x^5-x^4-2x+1 -> 3, 0.7, 0.453 ...
```

Comment: \$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = 0\$ isn't enough, right? The sequence must converge

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes, the sequence must converge

Comment: Could you add test cases?

Comment: Sequence of rational or real numbers? I see only reals in answers and test cases

Comment: @lesobrod [Rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number). The representation doesn't matter as long as it's reasonable. Any number with a finite amount of non zero digits in its decimal expansion is rational which is what the answers and test cases are using. For example `1.23 = 123/100`. What you can't do is output for example `sqrt(2)` or pi.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, so could you clarify: 'sequence must converge' - does that mean that the absolute difference from the true answer between each element and the next element must be always decreasing?  Or is it Ok if the difference increases sometimes, as long as it decreases in the long run?  If not Ok, can 2 adjacent elements ever have the same absolute difference?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen absolute difference decreasing is not enough I think - consider 1/n gets closer and closer to -1 but converges to 0. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Definition

Comment: @qwr - Actually I meant the Q the other way around (see my R answer): is it Ok to have a sequence that - on average - gets closer and closer to the correct answer and indeed arrives at the correct answer in the end, but that some intermediate steps may briefly get further away (before getting closer again).

Comment: @qwr - But I think your wikipedia link answers it: thanks!  It seems to be Ok (if I understood correctly...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen "arrives at the correct answer" is a little vague, for example the sequence 1/n for n=1,2,3,... never equals 0 for any n, but gets arbitrarily close. The epsilon-delta definition is the precise definition of convergence.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> <s>19</s> <s>12</s> 8 bytes

```
LÅ¼{.Δβd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f53DroT3VeuemnNuU8v@/oQEQcEUb6Rjo6Brr6BoCaSDLSMcwFgA)

Takes as an input a number \$n\$ and the coefficients list, from the highest power to the smallest one, and returns \$a_n\$.

Requires the leading coefficient to be positive. If that is invalid, we need +2 bytes to fix it by adding `*н` after `β`

If this is invalid because we may not assume \$\tan\$ has infinite precision, then the following 13 bytes alternative could be used, which uses a spacing of \$\frac1 n\$ for the \$x\$s inside a bound:

```
*ÄO(D(Ÿ¹/.Δβd
```

### Explanation

Finds the non-negative value of \$p(x)\$ (\$p(x) \cdot c_m\$ in the version which doesn't require a positive leading coefficient) with the smallest \$x\$ among the values \$ x = \tan(i) \$ for \$ 1 \leq i \leq n \$. The \$\tan\$ of integers is dense in \$\mathbb{R}\$ (Since \$ n\mod \pi\$ is dense in the range \$(0, \pi)\$ ), so we can get arbitrarily close to the target number, and since we always keep \$x\$s as \$n\$ increases the sequence is non-increasing. Additionally, uses the fact that base conversion is the same action as evaluating a polynomial at the base, and that 05AB1E's base conversion builtin works well with non-integers.

```
L          Get the range [1, 2, 3, ..., n]
Å¼         Calculate the tangent of each number in that range
{          And sort those
.Δ         Now find the first value such that
 β          When converting the polynomial from that base
 d          It is non-negative
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 89 or 143 bytes

### Answer #1

If it is enough to find *one (any)* real root
we can use next facts:

- All real roots of odd degree polynomial [are bounded inside interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689575/proof-that-every-polynomial-of-odd-degree-has-one-real-root) \$[-M,M]\$
  where \$M = \max\left(1,\sum_{k=0}^{2n}|a_k|\right)\$  (\$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}|a_k|\$ if coefficients are integers)
- [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) *always* converges to *some* root of continuous function if they exist in given interval

...and do not use extra-power built-ins.
Fortunately `$MachineEpsilon` works well with TIO. So next code produces stream of *rational* approximations for one of the real roots. Input: array of coefficients.

```
With[{c=#,m=Total[Abs/@#]},If[Abs[Echo@#1-#2]>$MachineEpsilon,p=Fold[x#1+#2&,0,c]/.x->#&;d=(#1+#2)/2;If[p@#1*p@d>0,#0[d,#2],#0[#1,d]]]&[-m,m]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYw9C4MwFEX/SuEV6cezGmmHIpF0sNDBrdAhZEgTRcGYgBkE8bfb2OXee@5wjPRtbaTvlFwbun463/JZUUBDKzlxgm/rZc8f3zFhIMSCr2YDXqrWMiAxZKLYV1K13VCXbux6O6CjT9trPgE5QxZhikoklykuIMo1PfzfY5LlweSC4uSYLlKElGsMtm0AQS2EiHhs0IReGzZfcReT@xa4uy3rDw)
Optimization is welcome!

### Answer #2

The next code works well with Mathematica desktop
(input is array of coefficients and output are approximations of *all* real roots):

```
Do[Echo[x/.NSolve[Fold[x#1+#2&,0,#],x,Reals,WorkingPrecision->n]],{n,∞}]&
```

But on TIO nor `N`, nor `WorkingPrecision` are not working(
So just like this (n>20 make no sense):

```
Do[Echo@Round[x/.NSolve[Fold[x#1+#2&,0,#],x,Reals],10.^-n],{n,20}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yU/2jU5I98hKL80LyW6Ql/PLzg/pyw12i0/B8hVNtRWNlLTMdBRjtWp0AlKTcwpjtUxNNCL082L1anO0zEyqI1V@x9QlJlX4pDmUG2io6BraAkidBRMa/8DAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```r
\(x,n,a=polyroot(x),c=Re(a[!Im(a)])%/%1+0:n/n)c[order(sapply(c,\(y)x%*%y^seq(!x)/y)^2)][1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY_NbgIhFIXX-hTXmEmgMhHspjGdZRfdtImxm_oTKQUlYcAC086s-iDd6KIP5dvIVCdpWBC45zvn3J-jP5y-N4NNoSoronYW1SQ6UzCZM4r5W0A1vk8fMAT3Kf2X11FC0gMybqsFN_nT8xxDR0N04GWsvIX57OUBtALut1UpbQQdIJTcGJDWVdtdv--di0F-FL9VVPnd6XWZsi3hxd6Zpp2laCKKmUR8MXgsEccrnI0zNqJTO7ZYLJx_lx4Fvt-bBgmyRA2us5usWSdTNKjxuMHrCV4t2OqacGydC4HyCaHpMJy2Ek4qpYVODQM4BflkVK9v-1dXNmWUUnJtSuq_bhh6Q1DahwjtFKSRZYcnVSWtkN1yqAVIK6M0cb1EXh5x13H_sUvRw-FynwE)

Uses the R `polyroot` function to find the (limited-precision) root `a`, then for each element `n` of the sequence, divides `floor(a)`-`ceiling(a)` into `n` steps and returns the one with the smallest absolute result after applying the polynomial.
The final result is still limited by R's precision*, but the approach should work in principle, and is not affected by the limited-precision of the `polyroot` function (as long as it is correct to the nearest integer).

The limit as `n` tends to infinity is the true real root of the polynomial; however, successive elements of the sequence may have increasing absolute differences from the true root, depending on whether partitioning the interval into `n-1` or `n` steps allows a better solution.  For a convergent-at-every-step sequence, divide into `2^n` instead of `n` steps, for 4 more bytes: try it [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY_PSsMwHMfP21P8xigkLmVNZSDDHj14URjztK0sxmQLpMlMUm1PPoUnL_PgQ-1tTN0KEkLgl8_3z-_r2x1PH9vRtpC14UFZgxoSrC6oSGmG2bNHDb6NAxiDfRPu3akgIPKAtN0pznT68LjE0KshWHAi1M7AcvF0B0oCc7u6EiaA8uArpjUIY-vdfjh01gYvXoufOsj05lSuY7YhrDhY3XZ_MZrwYiEQW43uK8TwBifThE6yeV6aabyYr6x7EQ55djjoFnGyRi1ukqukLaMxGjV42uIyx5sV3VxSPjv3gqM0J1k8FMfNuBVSKq5iSw9WQppPmvJ6eHGlczojl66k-WuHYTAGqZwPQGcgtKh6aWRqYbjol0MdTvIsKgZRk2dh3_P_8XO54_H8_gI).

---

(*) Note that this approach is actually *very* limited by R's precision, as the `a[!Im(a)]` part of the code (=get non-complex roots) fails quite easily due to floating-point inaccuracies: the test link overcomes this by redefining R's `` `!` `` (logical-NOT) operator to return `TRUE` as long as its argument is sufficiently small.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES7), 74 bytes

*-26 bytes (!) thanks to @CommandMaster*

A port of [@CommandMaster's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258023/58563).

Expects `(p)(n)` where `p` is the coefficient list from lowest to highest.

```javascript
p=>g=(n,m)=>n?g(n-1,p.reduce((q,c,i)=>q+c*(v=Math.tan(n))**i)<0|v>m?m:v):m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY47DoMwEER7TuFylxhkSBGJxFClzAkQhWXMJ8I2v7jK3QkBEUXaYvbNaDRP4cQkx7afA2NLtVR86XlaczBUI09NVoMJItqHoypfUgEMVNJ2dYaT9MHxh5ibcBYGDKLvt3hjb5fqTCcOE71cc4@QnESUsO2CmBT0QJc/zX6J9YkOI97RecdHxRbwCi@s7HgXsoGe8JRIaybbqbCzNVTw3evUOClAhIgxhojLBw)

#### Commented

```javascript
p =>                // p[] = list of coefficients
g = (               // g is a recursive function taking:
  n,                //   n = counter
  m                 //   m = minimum result, initially undefined
) =>                //
n ?                 // if n is not equal to 0:
  g(                //   do a recursive call:
    n - 1,          //     decrement n
    p.reduce(       //     using q as accumulator,
    (q, c, i) =>    //     for each coefficient c at index i:
      q +           //       add to q:
      c * (         //         c multiplied by v ** i
        v =         //         where v = tan(n)
        Math.tan(n) //
      ) ** i        //
    )               //     end of reduce()
    < 0 |           //     if the evaluation of the polynomial is negative
    v > m ?         //     or v is greater than m:
      m             //       keep m unchanged
    :               //     else:
      v             //       update m to v
  )                 //   end of recursive call
:                   // else:
  m                 //   stop and return m
```

Comment: The test case of `[7]` should be `[1, 7]`, I think.

Comment: You can save 7 bytes by replacing `(c>0?c:-c)` with `c*c`

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY47DoMwEER7TuFylxhkSBGJxFClzAkQhWXMJ8I2v7jK3QkBEUXaYvbNaDRP4cQkx7afA2NLtVR86XlaczBUI09NVoMJItqHoypfUgEMVNJ2dYaT9MHxh5ibcBYGDKLvt3hjb5fqTCcOE71cc4@QnESUsO2CmBT0QJc/zX6J9YkOI97RecdHxRbwCi@s7HgXsoGe8JRIaybbqbCzNVTw3evUOClAhIgxhojLBw "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") by porting my latest version, and it's quite likely there are JavaScript-specific optimizations I missed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 8 bytes

```
∆P≬İ⌊=cḞ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuItyIiwiIiwi4oiGUOKJrMSw4oyKPWPhuJ4iLCIiLCJbMSwgMCwgMCwgLTJdXG44Il0=)

I think this is valid. Takes list of coefficients and then the nth term to generate.

### Explained

```
∆P≬İ⌊=cḞ
∆P       # Get roots from polynomial with coefficients. Returns a list of exact algebraic numbers because sympy.
  ≬   c  # Get the first root where:
   İ⌊=   #   the root is real
       Ḟ # format to n decimal places
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 30 bytes

```
⊞υΣ↔θ⊞υ±ΣυＦη«≔⊘Συζ§≔υ‹↨θζ⁰ζ⟦Ｉζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xCsIwEIZn@xQZL9CCXVycqouCSMExdIhtbAppgr2kSMVnj1cxcDfc/33c32o5tU6aGOuAGkLObmGE6o7OBK/gyTnfZwldVS8pXI3wAw83MdCcvbNNhTj0Fk7SzKpLSs4Wsv6s8mfbqdf66KIQ4SCRClYlZ9uk1tNgPYijRA8Lbyj6xChESUqago6yod01sZjNFw) Takes the polynomial and a number of terms (but because it uses floats there's no point asking for more than 50). Assumes that the leading term is positive. Explanation: Simple binary search over the bound of roots given by @CommandMaster.

```
⊞υΣ↔θ
```

Set the upper bound to the sum of the absolute coefficients.

```
⊞υ±Συ
```

Set the lower bound to the negation of the upper bound.

```
Ｆη«
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
≔⊘Συζ
```

Calculate the average of the bounds.

```
§≔υ‹↨θζ⁰ζ
```

Evaluate the polynomial at that point and update the appropriate bound.

```
⟦Ｉζ
```

Also output the next approximation.